# Get the status from ClientErrorException

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, http-response-codes

About half of the many constructors of `ClientErrorException` take a `Response.Status`. But why is there no way of getting it back? Doesn't it have any purpose other than being validated in `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException#validate(javax.ws.rs.core.Response, javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family)` ?

I thought the way of using it would be extending it

```
public class WhateverInvalidInRequestException extends ClientErrorException {

    public WhateverInvalidInRequestException (String message) {
        super(message, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

And then use a single `ExceptionMapper` for all the subclasses, which is very convenient

```
@Provider
public class ClientErrorExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ClientErrorException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ClientErrorException exception) {
        return Response.status(exception.getStatus()).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

But there is no such a thing as `exception.getStatus()`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it this way:

```
exception.getResponse().getStatus()
```